# google cloud sdk is installed in my EC2 instance and I could access gcloud. But bq is not available even though I see it in the list of components

Tags: amazon-ec2, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, bq, matillion

I am installed google-cloud-sdk in my matillion instance hosted on EC2. I am able to access gcloud command in the ssh instance and also by using a bash component in my matillion.
However, I am not able to run bq commands. I see it has been installed as part of the cloud sdk. I was able to configure my account and everything. But it doesn't work.[image]

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#before_you_begin), its necessary that you activated the BigQuery API in order to use the bq command-line tool.

These are all the steps that you need to follow:

1. In the Cloud Console, on the project selector page, select or create
   a Cloud project.
2. Install and initialize the Cloud SDK.
3. BigQuery is automatically enabled in new projects. To activate BigQuery in a preexisting project, go to [Enable the BigQuery API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/bigquery.googleapis.com).

I also was getting the same error than you and activating the API was the solution.

Comment: I have activated the Big query API in GCP  but it still did not work.